# MDX ORDER by multiply measures

Tags: mdx

Suppose that i have next MDX query

```
select 
{
   [Measures].[Measure1],
   [Measures].[Measure2],
} on columns,
{   
   ORDER([Dim].Children, [Measures].[Measure1], desc)
} on rows
from [Cube]
```

which selects two measures and sorts rows by first one.
How can sort by two measures, frist sort by Measure1 and then sort by Measure2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works on AdvWrks for me:

```
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[Reseller Order Quantity]
   ,[Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount]
  } ON 0
 ,Order
  (
    Order
    (
      [Product].[Product].[Product].MEMBERS
     ,[Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount]
     ,BDESC
    )
   ,[Measures].[Reseller Order Quantity]
   ,BDESC
  ) ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Maybe you need to swap the order around and use `BDESC`:

```
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[Measure1]
   ,[Measures].[Measure2]
  } ON COLUMNS
 ,{
    Order
    (
      Order
      (
        [Dim].Children
       ,[Measures].[Measure2]
       ,BDESC
      )
     ,[Measures].[Measure1]
     ,BDESC
    )
  } ON ROWS
FROM [Cube];
```

Comment: Yes, using BDESC instead of DESC helped. Thanks.

Comment: @Sourav_Agasti not sure - I believe swapping Measure1 for Measure2 was more important?

Comment: @FCBshnik - Can you please let us know the output when in @whytheq's answer, you have `DESC` instead of `BDESC`?

Comment: @Sourav_Agasti compared to your script I would say swapping Measure1 for Measure2 was important if you want to order by Measure1 and then Measure2? Hard to say what influence the hierarchical order was having on his original script. BDESC/BASC are my personal defaults when using ORDER - I generally don't seem to use DESC/ASC

Comment: In that case, it needs to be explicit if changing the order of measures did the trick or `BDESC`. I am not able to repro that on my sample cube. Waiting for @FCBshnik to throw some light.

Comment: @Sourav_Agasti try the AdvWrks script I have above BUT swap the two measures inside the nested order functions it is then equivalent to your answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71591/discussion-between-sourav-agasti-and-whytheq).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select 
{
   [Measures].[Measure1],
   [Measures].[Measure2]
} on columns,
{   
   ORDER(ORDER([Dim].Children, [Measures].[Measure1], desc), [Measures].[Measure2], DESC)
} on rows
from [Cube]
```

**EDIT:** Reason why it will not work is because the order of measures needed to be changed. Below is what I think happens:

Control first goes to inner set and it is ordered by the inner measure. This set returned is then sorted by the outer measure. The overall effect is that the outer measure supersedes the sorting by inner measure. So if we wanted to sort by m1->m2 then m1 needs to be the outer measure and m2, the inner measure.

Comment: This answer will give rows ordered by Measures2 with ties being decided by Measures1 .... the question asks for this the other way around.

Comment: Yep, now I see it. Was curious if DESC was the bad boy, which apparently isnt