# How would you order MDX query

Tags: mdx

I  am unable to figure out how I would do a simple "order by" clause.

Below is my query - how would I order it by `Service Name` then by `Adjusted Incidents`?

```
SELECT 
  {[Measures].[Adjusted Incidents]} ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    {
        [Completed Inspections].[Service Name].[Service Name].ALLMEMBERS
      * 
        [Inspected Items].[Item Name].[Item Name].ALLMEMBERS
    }
  DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION  ON ROWS
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    {
      [Completed Inspections].[Customer Id].&[DRHOD]
     ,[Completed Inspections].[Customer Id].&[EMHST]
     ,[Completed Inspections].[Customer Id].&[EXHOU]
     ,[Completed Inspections].[Customer Id].&[ETRAD]
    } ON COLUMNS
  FROM [Inspections]
)
WHERE 
  (
    [Calendar].[Month].&[2015-05-01T00:00:00]
   ,[Completed Inspections].[Is Reinspection].&[False]
  )
CELL PROPERTIES VALUE;
```

Comment: maybe a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28689824/mdx-order-by-multiply-measures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a clause for order in `mdx` similar to `sql`.

You need to apply the function `ORDER` to any sets that you wish to order. Here is the `msdn` definition:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145587.aspx

Nesting orders isn't so trivial in `mdx` - the inside application of order is the order you want applied second the outside nest is the order you want applied first:

```
SELECT 
  {[Measures].[Adjusted Incidents]} ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    Order
    (
      Order
      (
        {
            [Completed Inspections].[Service Name].[Service Name].ALLMEMBERS
          * 
            [Inspected Items].[Item Name].[Item Name].ALLMEMBERS
        }
       ,[Measures].[Adjusted Incidents]
       ,BDESC  //<<you have 4 choices here BDESC, BASC, DESC, or ASC
      )
     ,[Completed Inspections].[Service Name].CurrentMember.Member_Caption
     ,BDESC    //<<you have 4 choices here BDESC, BASC, DESC, or ASC
    )
  DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION  ON ROWS
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    {
      [Completed Inspections].[Customer Id].&[DRHOD]
     ,[Completed Inspections].[Customer Id].&[EMHST]
     ,[Completed Inspections].[Customer Id].&[EXHOU]
     ,[Completed Inspections].[Customer Id].&[ETRAD]
    } ON COLUMNS
  FROM [Inspections]
)
WHERE 
  (
    [Calendar].[Month].&[2015-05-01T00:00:00]
   ,[Completed Inspections].[Is Reinspection].&[False]
  )
CELL PROPERTIES VALUE;
```

Comment: thanks for this, it worked perfect!! Saved me a headache!

Comment: no problem - the order of the nested orders caused me some serious head-scratching when I first played with them